# Conditional ASP.NET MVC razor sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to define this section only if some property (`Model.ReadOnly`) is `false`.

```
@section toolbar {
    <div class="tool">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink( Resources.Strings.Edit, "Edit", "Profile" )
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink( Resources.Strings.Delete, "Delete", "Profile" )
        </div>
    </div >
}
```

I tried wrapping it up in `@if ( !Model.ReadOnly ) {}` but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

---

I do not want to define an empty section ([as @itsmatt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097162/conditional-asp-net-mvc-razor-sections/7097248#7097248)), the layout of my page changes whether the section is defined or not (using `IsSectionDefined( "toolbar" )`).

Comment: You should just have to throw `<text>` and `</text>` tags around the section declaration. See my answer.

Comment: My solution: https://gist.github.com/brynner/7de01fb7446bddd9116847323d18b10d

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This should work.

```
@if (!Model.ReadOnly)
{
    <text>
    @section toolbar {

    }
    </text>
}
```

I never said it would be pretty ;-)

Comment: In my case i didn't need the <text> tags

Comment: I can confirm that I also didn't need this `<text>` tags (ASP.NET MVC v5.2.7).

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
@section SomeSection {
   @if (!Model.ReadOnly)
   {

   }
}
```

Essentially flipping where the conditional is.  This essentially results in an empty section if `Model.ReadOnly` is true.

---

Update:

So, what about moving that section to a `PartialView` and doing something like:

```
@Html.Partial("MyAction")
```

in your View and then let the `MyAction` return you the appropriate `PartialView` based on the ReadOnly value?  Something like:

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction()
{
   ...

   // determine readonly status - could have passed this to the action I suppose    
   if (ReadOnly)
   {
      return PartialView("TheOneThatDefinesTheSection");
   }
   else
   {
      return PartialView("TheOneThatDoesNotDefineTheSection");
   }
}
```

Seems like that would work just fine.

Comment: No, it wouldn't work for me. I'm doing some logic wether the section is defined or not.

Comment: OK, so I added another idea in my answer which worked in my test example just fine.  Maybe it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand,

See:

[Razor If/Else conditional operator syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607843/razor-if-else-conditional-operator-syntax)

basically (para-phrasing), ... *Razor currently supports a subset of C# expressions without using @() and unfortunately, ternary operators are not part of that set.*

also, this may be a way around the issue:

[conditional logic in mvc view vs htmlhelper vs action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329101/conditional-logic-in-mvc-view-vs-htmlhelper-vs-action)

basically, use the if logic to call a partialview to satisfy your criteria.

**[edit]** this was my basic thinking (where your @section code is defined in that partial):

```
@if(!Model.ReadOnly) 
{
    @Html.Partial("toolbar")
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I'm not asking how `if` statements work. I'm trying to define a section **only** if a condition is verified. I don't know where you got that I want to use a ternary operator.

Comment: ok -no worries, just covering all the bases. i still 'think' my idea of defining the toolbar @section in a partial view and then checking that may work (or not!!)... [see my clumsy edit] :)